# Applying git-filter-repo to subtree

Tags: git, subtree, git-filter-repo

I have an existing git repository (e.g. in my organisation's private repository) consisting of several sub-projects organised in specific folders. I used `git subtree` to split the sub-projects and push them to a public repository:

```
git subtree --prefix="subprojectA/" split --rejoin
git subtree --prefix="subprojectA/" push ~/new_repos_subprojectA subA
```

I can now use `git subtree pull` and `push` to keep the repositories in sync:

```
git subtree --prefix="subprojectA/" pull new_repos_subprojectA subA
```

But, I need to eliminate specific files with confident data from the public repository and use `git-filter-repo` to a clone of the new repository:

```
git filter-repo --invert-paths --path confident.properties
```

When I now want to pull changes in the new subproject, git complains with

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Is there any way to merge the projects after applying `git filter-repo`?

Comment: In general, any "filtered" repository results in a new and different repository, and after this point, neither repository should *ever* be introduced to the other one. If you want a filtered version as an output, treat it as output-only: never take anything *directly* back from it into the original repository. At most, turn these into patches (with `git format-patch` for instance) and then apply them.

Comment: It's possible to violate this rule (with great care) using `git cherry-pick`, but the patch method is safer.